# twitter4j using generic argument names

Tags: java, twitter4j

So is it just for me? but twitter4j method arguments use generic naming, for example
`getUserListMembers(long l, int i, long l1)` it makes it hard to work out what variables it need, for everything I do I need to refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they have appropriately named parameters:

> [getUserListMembers(long listOwnerId, int listId, long cursor)](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/2.2.1/twitter4j/api/ListMembersMethods.html#getUserListMembers(long,%20int,%20long))

Are you sure you're not just looking at a jar which has the javadocs stripped?

Comment: I'm adding the `twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar` from the twitter4j lib folder to my project librarys